# Error : Incompatible types Possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    public int[][] kClosest(int[][] points, int k) {
        PriorityQueue<int[]> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((int[] a, int[] b) -> Integer.compare(dis(a),dis(b)));
        for(int[] i : points) {
            pq.offer(i);
            if(pq.size() > k) {
                pq.poll();
            }
        }
        int[][] res = new int[k][2];
        int c = 0;
        for(int[] i : pq) {
            res[c] = i;
            c++;
        }
        return res;
    }
    public double dis(int[] a) {
        return a[0]*a[0] + a[1]*a[1];
    }
}
```

Error  Message :

```
  Line 3: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
        PriorityQueue<int[]> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((int[] a, int[] b) -> Integer.compare(dis(a),dis(b)));
                                                                                               ^
```

I was trying to solve a leetcode question But I kept getting this error. I am not even using double anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer.compare(dis(a),dis(b))
```

`Integer.compare` takes two `int`s; you're passing it two `double`s.

Use `Double.compare(dis(a), dis(b))` instead.

---

It is worth pointing out, however, that the `dis` method could return `int` instead:

```
public double dis(int[] a) {
    return a[0]*a[0] + a[1]*a[1];
}
```

is doing the whole calculation using integer arithmetic, and then widening the result to `double`. Effectively:

```
public double dis(int[] a) {
    int result = a[0]*a[0] + a[1]*a[1];
    return (double) result;
}
```

If you are converting to double to avoid overflow, it doesn't help: the overflow will have already occurred before you do the widening to double.

If you don't expect overflow, you can simply change the return type to `int`, and then use either `Integer.compare` or `Double.compare` to compare them.

If you do expect (or want to avoid) overflow, make sure you're using double arithmetic:

```
public double dis(int[] a) {
    return (double) a[0]*a[0] + (double) a[1]*a[1];
}
```

---

Also, note that the comparator can be expressed more concisely:

```
Comparator.comparingDouble((int[] a) -> dis(a))
// or
Comparator.comparingDouble(this::dis)
```

instead of

```
(int[] a, int[] b) -> Double.compare(dis(a),dis(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public double dis(int[] a)
```

Yes, you are using `double`s.

Comment: Thank you I for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The function `dis` returns a double. You are trying to compare two doubles with `Integer.compare`. Thus, Java is converting doubles back to ints for you, causing the error message.

Comment: Thank you, I for pointing out my mistake.